# How can I set “This block (override)” programmatically on a view's display

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I need help about a specific implementation in Drupal 8.

I have been trying for two days to create a view programmatically, or more precisely to create a new display of an existing view.

The objective is to create (at the same time as creating new content) a duplicate display of a view, which is almost the same than the original, with just the title and a condition in filter criteria (a node id) changed, in order that the final user never needs to add display or modify the view.

The issue that I am coming up against is that the generated view's display lost an important property, the “This block (override)” parameter is replaced by the default state “All displays (excepts overridden)” so once I have generated the second view’s display programmatically, the first view’s display has its properties (title, filter criteria) replaced inevitably by the values of the second.

So I would like to programmatically set the parameter “All displays (excepts overridden)” at “This block (override)” but I haven’t found anything of relevance in the D8 API.

Thank you in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

[image]

function HOOK_node_insert(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $node) {

```
if ($node->type->target_id == "SPECIFIC_CONTENT_TYPE") {

    $node_title = $node->getTitle();
    $node_id = $node->id();
    $machine_title = strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$node_title));
    $block_id = 'block_'.$machine_title;

    $view = Views::getView("api_domain");//"api_domain" is the view's machine name
    if (empty($view)) {
        return;
    }
    $display_id = 'default';
    if (!$view->access($display_id)) {
        return;
    }

    $view->newDisplay('block',$node_title, $block_id);
    $options_array = array(
        'id' => 'field_api_domain_target_id',
        'table' => 'node__field_api_domain',
        'field' => 'field_api_domain_target_id',
        'relationship' => 'none',
        'group_type' => 'group',
        'admin_label' => '',
        'operator' => '=', 'value' =>  array('value' => $node_id));

    $view->setHandler($display_id, 'filter', 'field_api_domain_target_id', $options_array);//works
    //$view->setTitle($node_title);//doesn't works
    $view->display_handler->setOption('title', $node_title);// works
    //$view->display_handler->overrideOption('title', $node_title);// works too, but the "override" problem still persists
    $view->save();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find a way to do this with the methods of Views API, you can try another approach by using the view entity (storage), which provides a more direct access to the display settings in an array.

**Example**

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('myview');
$storage = $view->storage;
// add a new display
$storage->addDisplay('block', $new_title, $block_id);
// get the new display by reference
$new_display = &$storage->getDisplay($block_id);
// copy the configuration and change the filter settings
$old_display = $storage->getDisplay($old_display_id);
$new_display = array_replace_recursive($old_display, $new_display);
$new_display['display_options']['filters']['nid']['value']['value'] = 123;

$storage->save();
```

Comment: My problem is solved with your approach. Thank you very much !